Is there an easy way to mentally calculate mean an variance?
Giving a generic numerical data is there an easy way to calculate mean an variance mentally or at least some easy formula that minimize the error with the correct mean and variance?

Welcome to Cross Validated! Do you mean some easy formula besides $\bar x = \frac{1}{n}\sum x_i$ and $s^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum\left(x_i - \bar x_i\right)^2?$

In many cases there are easy substitutes, such as using a median to describe the average and some multiple of a quantile range (such as the IQR) to describe the spread.  So: what is the reason you are doing these mental calculations and how accurate do they need to be?  We need to understand that so we can determine what a relevant and useful answer might be.

I know the formulas I was wondering if there were some easy calculation tricks that can allow to perform these calculation without the need of excel or other software. My main purpose is to find if there is an easy way to renomalize such data to a normal aleatory variable without great information loss so that one can easyl extimate the long tails of such values. Let me give an example.

@pgiacome Please do give an example.
